# Properties of continuous functions-limit exists but the improper integral does not exist

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

What are some examples of continuous functions with the domain $[1,\infty)$ with the property that the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{1}^n f(x)dx$ exists but the improper integral $\int_{1}^\infty f(x)dx$ does not exist.

Comment: $n\to \infty\,?$

Comment: yes sorry, typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Periodic functions come to mind; try something like $\sin (k x)$ for the right constant $k.$

Comment: would something like $sin(\pi x)$ work?

Comment: Something like it, but that one doesn't work.

Comment: do you mind explaining why it would not work? i think i am a bit confused.

Comment: integrate $\sin(\pi x)$ and see what you get

Comment: ok yeah i see...

Comment: would a negative integer in place of k work then?

Comment: Try $\,\,k=2\pi.$